Wrapping DataTable component from PrimeVue
I'm building a library of VueJS components based on PrimeVue, and for this I would like to wrap one of their UI component like it is described on their documentation :
https://tailwind.primevue.org/guides/building-ui-library/
I've followed exactly what it says but the component doesn't render at all and no errors are shown.
I've reproduced the issue in this sandbox : codesandbox
In the sandbox as you can see the DataTable is shown if it comes directly from primevue library, but if it's the custom one created it does not display the data even though the table tag is created.
Thanks for your help.
